# Outlook VSTO in ItemAdd event handler creating new mailitem always has null wordeditor

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I'm trying to create an Outlook add-in that processes a certain MailItem and forwards the result on to another group of people.  In order to do the processing, I believe I need to use the WordEditor in order to get the proper formatting, but when I try to access that object, it returns null.  I'm able to send the mail properly when I don't access the WordEditor, so it's probably something simple I've overlooked.  How can I access the WordEditor for this new MailItem?

```
    Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
    Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
    Outlook.Items items;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        items = inbox.Items;
        items.ItemAdd +=
            new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);

    }

    void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
   {
        string filter = "Filter";
        if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
            if (Item != null)
            {
                if (mail.MessageClass == "IPM.Note" &&
                           mail.Subject.ToUpper().Contains(filter.ToUpper())
                           && mail.Attachments.Count == 1)
                {

                    Outlook.Attachments attachments = mail.Attachments;
                    if (attachments != null)
                    {

                        Outlook.Attachment file = attachments[1];
                        //Process attachment...
                        Outlook.MailItem newMail = this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                        Outlook.Inspector insp = newMail.GetInspector;
                        insp.Activate();
                        newMail.Subject = "Subject";
                        newMail.To = "email@example.com";
                        Word.Document emailBody = insp.WordEditor as Word.Document;
                        //emailBody is always null
                        newMail.Send();                          

                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newMail);
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(file);
                    }
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachments);
                }
            }
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `MailIten.HTMLBody` appropriately without using the Inspector object and the Word Object Model.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  If it turns out to be technically impossible to access the WordEditor here, I suppose I'll need to do this, but I'd prefer to let Word create the "HTML" for me than need to style it on my own.

Comment: Why not just hardcode the HTML (that is what your Word Object Model would essentially do anyway) and just replace the placeholders with the recipient specific data?